# How to customize VS intellitrace collectionplan.xml to trace a function inside a nested private class

Tags: intellitrace

I'm now using Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1 to debug an app.  I customized the collectionplan.xml according to this article http://blog.qetza.net/en/2010/03/08/vs-2010-personnalisation-des-vnements-de-lintellitrace/ to trace my own code.  When I want to trace a function inside a nested private class, that event doesn't show up in the diagnostic window.

I tried to change the `TypeName` tag to *<full qualified outer class id>/<nested class name>* which is found from the IL, but failed.

Is it impossible or I misspelled the the `TypeName`?

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I got the answer by running `GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName`.  The seperator should be `+`.  So, if you want to trace a function inside a nested private class, here is an example:

```
<TypeName>Namespace.OuterClassName+NestedClassName</TypeName>
<MethodName>YourMethodName</MethodName>
<MethodId>Namespace.OuterClassName+NestedClassName.YourMethodName(...):ReturnType</MethodId>
```

I've tried in VS2015 with Update 1 on a nested private class.  And, it works.

Hope my answer can help someone who happens to find this question.